# How to calculate the outcome of a simple dice in 3D space

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, formula, dice

So imagine you have a simple dice with 6 faces in 3D space.
The dice has been made out of standard HTML elements and transformed into a 3D object. The starting position is always the same facing 1 upwards, 2 at the leftside and 3 toward the you (viewport).

Now you're able to rotate the dice using transform: rotateX, rotateY, rotateZ. For obvious reasons you're only able to rotate the dice by steps of 90deg each direction (negative aswell). Now what kind of formula do I have to use to calculate the final outcome.

Small example lets say: X = 3 (270deg), Y = 1 (90deg), Z = 2 (180deg) will result into throwing 3.

Do you see any logic involved into this because I dont seem to fully understand it.

Comment: Can you explain how your example results in the stated outcome?

Comment: Sure, so I'm using GSAP as animation framework to take care of the rotations. To mimic the reality I only want to throw the dice 90deg for each axis. Which means if I would throw 360deg at X-asis it would result into being 1 again. In my code 1 flip means 90 degrees (and it can go up to 4 which is 360 degrees)

Comment: What is the result of each of the following from the initial state: x=1, y=0, z=0?  x=0, y=1, z=0? x=0, y=0, z=1?

Comment: I've actually used a dice in real life and recreated it. Meaning the initial state would be: top: 1, front: 3, left: 2, right: 5, back: 4, bottom: 6,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's represent all those numbers as an object:

```
 const faces = { top: 1, left: 2, front: 3, bottom: 4, right: 5, back: 6 };
```

Now if you rotate it to the right for example, you could swap  the involved faces:

```
const rotateToLeft = prev => ({
  top: prev.top,
  left: prev.front,
  front: prev.right,
  bottom: prev.bottom,
  right: prev.back,
  back: prev.left
});
```

Now you could do that with every direction, and then just rotate the dice as long as you need to get the result:

```
 let result = faces;

 for(let turn = 0; turn < 4 + Math.floor((X % 360) / 90); turn++)
   result = rotateToLeft(result);

 // repeat for y and z
```